# Efficient way to reduce a subset of vector using thrust/cuda

Tags: cuda, thrust, reduction

Let us say, we have a thrust device vector of size 10^16 and another vector of size 10^8 containing some indices (not necessarily sorted). We want to sum all the elements of the first vector if it's index is in the second vector.

A naive approach to do so would be to use transform_reduce of thrust. However, I believe it'll involve iterating through all the elements of the first vector.

Is there an efficient way?

Comment: Probably a permutation iterator: https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1permutation__iterator.html

Comment: Thank you. Indeed permutation_iterator is what I need here, the code runs faster with it.

Comment: It would be good if you add a short answer explaining your solution for future visitors

Answer (score 2):

Following talonmies suggestion of permutation iterator, here is the main body of the code that implements reduction of a subset of a vector. I purposefully, chose small vector sizes to explain the idea. For reasonable sizes, it is faster than using inner_product

```
    thrust::device_vector<double> vals(6);
    vals[0] = 2.0; vals[1] = 1.5; vals[2] = -1.2;
    vals[3] = 1.1; vals[4] = -4.3; vals[5] = 0.8;

    thrust::device_vector<int> indices(3);
    indices[0] = 1; indices[1] = 3; indices[2] = 5;

    thrust::device_vector<double> masks(6);

    for (auto elm:indices)
        masks[elm]=1.0;

    typedef thrust::device_vector<double>::iterator ValIterator;
    typedef thrust::device_vector<int>::iterator IndIterator;

    thrust::permutation_iterator<ValIterator, IndIterator> iter_begin(vals.begin(),
                                                                      indices.begin());
    thrust::permutation_iterator<ValIterator, IndIterator> iter_end(vals.end(),
                                                                    indices.end());

    double sum_reduce = thrust::reduce(iter_begin, iter_end);
    std::cout << "sum permutation iterator: " << sum_reduce << std::endl;

    double sum_inner_product = thrust::inner_product(vals.begin(), vals.end(),
                                                    masks.begin(), 0.0);
    std::cout << "sum inner product: " << sum_inner_product << std::endl;
```